# chai-http and async.each, throwing "Timeout of 2000ms exceeded..."

Tags: node.js, chai, async.js, chai-http

I have a simple test with chai-http, in which I try to test several URLs using async.each, but when the request takes more than 2 seconds, then I got the error.

```
it("it should GET the required images", (done) => {
    async.each(get_data, function(item, cb){
      chai
        .request(item.server_url.S)
        .get('/'+ item.endpoint.S + '?' + item.incoming.S)
        .end(function(err, res) {
          if(err) console.error(err);
          expect(err).to.be.null;
          expect(res).to.have.status(200);
          cb();
        });
    }, function(err){
      if(err) console.log(err);
      done();
    });
  });
```

I'm calling "done" as I think is correct, but I keep getting the error, what am I doing wrong? The error is showing even with no async, just the simple chai request, with only one request... so pretty sure is not an async issue but me using chaiHttp bad.

I also tried with "then/catch" instead of "end", but the result is the same.

I have a similar issue, in the same testing script but with the DB, if it takes more than 2 seconds with the query, it breaks... same error, also using "done":

```
before((done) => {
  // runs before all tests in this block
  const params = {
    TableName: "mytable"
  };

  mydb.scan(params, (err, records) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    for(let i = 0; i < records.Items.length; i++){
      //...some ifs, nothing async
    }
    done();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your test takes longer than 2000ms, consider to extend the timeout for your test might solve your problem

```
it("it should GET the required images", (done) => {
   this.timeout(5000);
   //...
```

Comment: Agreed.  Adding link to documentation for more explanation.  https://mochajs.org/#timeouts

Comment: It gives me .timeout is not a function. I can't find the solution

Comment: @YasinOkumuş Can you provide more detail?

Comment: @RyanWu, I think there is no difference between my code and the code in your answer, I put the line `this.timeout(5000);` and now I get `TypeError: this.timeout is not a function
    at Context.it (test/login.js:26:18)`

Comment: Interesting, can you try again with `function (done)` instead of  `(done)=>`?

Comment: Strange! Why  `function (done)` worked fine! why `(done)=>?` is problem with ES6?

Answer (score 0):

Give times in `this.timeout()` method as much as you need to finish the test

```
it('it should solve the timeout issue of a test in test level', function(done) {
    this.timeout(10000);
    done();
});
```